# Having trouble getting CPU temps using Open Hardware Monitor C#

Tags: c#, openhardwaremonitor

As the title describes I am having trouble getting CPU temps using the openhardwaremonitor.dll reference. I think I am running the program as an admin, I select run as admin when starting visual studio because I do not have the option to add an application.manifest file. This is the code I am using;

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;
namespace Get_CPU_Temp5
{
   class Program
   {
       public class UpdateVisitor : IVisitor
       {
           public void VisitComputer(IComputer computer)
           {
               computer.Traverse(this);
           }
           public void VisitHardware(IHardware hardware)
           {
               hardware.Update();
               foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardware.SubHardware) subHardware.Accept(this);
           }
           public void VisitSensor(ISensor sensor) { }
           public void VisitParameter(IParameter parameter) { }
       }
       static void GetSystemInfo()
       {
           UpdateVisitor updateVisitor = new UpdateVisitor();
           Computer computer = new Computer();
           computer.Open();
           computer.CPUEnabled = true;
           computer.Accept(updateVisitor);
           for (int i = 0; i < computer.Hardware.Length; i++)
           {
               if (computer.Hardware[i].HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
               {
                   for (int j = 0; j < computer.Hardware[i].Sensors.Length; j++)
                   {
                       if (computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                               Console.WriteLine(computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].Name + ":" + computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].Value.ToString() + "\r");
                   }
               }
           }
           computer.Close();
       }
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           while (true)
           {
               GetSystemInfo();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Error;
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'"

This error is at computer.Open();

I am using visual studio 2019.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue with trying to use openhardwaremonitor.dll with .Net core. The fix I found was to load system.management from Nuget. Apparently the system.management assemblies are not included in .net core like they are with .net Framework.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).